# Gambler's ruin problem - unsure about the number of rounds

Tags: probability, continuity

I am quite confused about the following question:

"Suppose that (initially) gambler has 10 dollars and adversary has 5 dollars. They
repeatedly throw a fair 6-sided die. If numbers 1 or 2 occur, gambler wins one
dollar from adversary, otherwise he loses one dollar to adversary. What is the
probability that gambler wins all adversary’s money?"

I believe that I should set this up in a continuous setting but I am not quite sure how to begin since it has discrete outcomes of the dice, which leaves the possibility as the rounds. But yet I believe there is also a way to do this via counting?

*Edit*: So given that I was over thinking the problem, could I set it up as follows ? $P(\text{1 or 2 appears}) = (\frac{2}{6})^15$. But something makes me think that this is too easy and naive. Having been directed that it is a gambler's ruin problem, I am wondering whether the number of rounds should be 5 or should one consider it to be 10 since that is how much the gambler starts off with.

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Why do you think it should be continuous?

Comment: Discrete only.  This has nothing to do with continuous random variables.

Comment: So given that I was over thinking the problem, could I set it up as follows ? $P(\text{1 or 2 appears}) = (\frac{2}{6})^5$. But something makes me think that this is too easy and naive. I tried to use counting but am not sure if I should look at the number of total possible outcomes and somehow work with that.

Comment: Have you been studying Markov processes in this class?

Comment: how many times is the dice rolled?

Comment: @hardmath no not yet

Comment: @samarbarrett I am not told, so I am assuming that just until an outcome where one person loses all their money ?

Comment: This is a version of the famous 'gambler's ruin' problem.

Comment: @BruceET Right, but would the number of rounds be 15 in this case considering that it is the gambler's ruin?

Comment: The solution to the gambler's ruin problem has a formula for the expected length of the game and another for the probability each player will win.

Comment: I realize you said you haven't covered Markov chains, but if you're interested you should check out the concept of exit distributions

Comment: @IntrnetHteMchne Will do, probably will cover it soon though I am some what familiar with markov chains from self learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started on solving this problem:

"What is the probability that gambler wins all adversary’s money?"

Let $P(k)$ denote the probability that adversary ($A$) loses all his money when his initial capital is $k$ dollars.

$P(k) = pP(k+1) + qP(k-1), \:\: k = 1, 2, ... ,N-1 \:\:\:\: (*)$

where $N$ is the total capital of the two players,
$pP(k+1)$ is the probability that $A$ wins the first round and subsequently loses all his money and $qP(k-1)$ is the probability that $A$ loses the first round and subsequently loses all his money.

Rewriting $(*)$ we have

$P(k+1) - \frac{1}{p} P(k) + \frac{q}{p} P(k-1) = 0, \:\: k = 1, 2, ... ,N-1 \:\:\:\: (**)$

which is a second-order homogenous linear-coefficient difference equation.

Note that we also have

$P(0) = 1$ and $P(N) = 0$

So to find $P(k)$ reduces to solving $(**)$ subject to these boundary conditions.

Let $P(k) = r^k$, $(**)$ becomes

$r^{k+1}-\frac{1}{p}r^k + \frac{q}{p} r^{k-1} = 0, \:\:\: p + q = 1$

Now solve this. Set $k = 1$, use the boundary conditions etc.

**edit:**

You set $k = 1$ to reduce it to a second order equation. 
Then you solve for $r$.
You get two solutions $r_1 = 1$ and $r_2 = q/p$.

Then

$P(k) = c_1 + c_2(q/p)^k$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants which you use the boundary conditions to find.

Comment: Thank you, I seem to understand this but shouldnt $k = 5$ in my case ? So I am not exactly sure what you mean by set $k = 1$ since it is fixed right ? As a result, wouldn't that give me 3 unknowns and 2 equations ?

Comment: @PutsandCalls I made an edit to my answer to adress your question

Comment: so just to double check, is it the case that $c_1 = 1$ and $c_2 = -1$ so that the probability of A losing his money is $p(k) = 1 - (\frac{\frac{2}{6}}{\frac{4}{6}})^5 \: \approx 0.96875$ ? Thank you

Comment: $$c_1 = \frac{-(q/p)^N}{1-(q/p)^N}$$
$$c_2 = \frac{1}{1-(q/p)^N}$$
$$P(k) = \frac{(q/p)^k-(q/p)^N}{1-(q/p)^N}$$
$$P(5) = \frac{(q/p)^5-(q/p)^{15}}{1-(q/p)^{15}}$$
$$q=\frac{4}{6}, \:\: p=\frac{2}{6}$$ @PutsandCalls

Comment: @PutsandCalls...Yes thats right, i mixed them up. $$q=\frac{2}{6}, \:p=\frac{4}{6}$$